# F# Sequences - how to return multiple rows

Tags: f#, sequence

```
let x = [for p in db.ParamsActXes do
                                            if p.NumGroupPar = grp then
                                                yield p.Num, p.Name]
```

Here is my sequence but the problem is it returns the list of tuples, I can't access single tuple element like

```
let str = "hello" + x.[1]
```

and that is the trouble.

how can I realize this functionary ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access the second element of a 2-tuple you can either use `snd` or pattern matching. So if `tup` is a 2-tuple, where the second element of `tup` is a string, you can either do:

```
let str = "hello" + snd tup
```

or

```
let (a,b) = tup
let st = "hello" + b
```

Note that `snd` only works with 2-tuples, not tuples with more than two elements.

Comment: And fst for first. thank you, that is solution for my current problem but just interesting what if there will be 3 elements or more ? second variant is bad for current task for me.

Comment: @nCdy: If there are three or more elements, you'll have to use pattern matching or define your own accessors (i.e. `let fst_of_3 (x,_,_) = x` `let snd_of_3 (_, x, _) = x` etc.)

Comment: @nCdy: It's the only one there is - other than reflection, which I doubt is a better solution in any situation where you know the type at compile-time. As I said you can define your own accessors, but at some point, you'll have to pattern match - there's no way around that.

Comment: but is there some way to make sequence to return not list of tuples but list of arrays or list of structures ?

Comment: @ncdy: You can yield `[|x, y|]` to get a sequence of arrays, but I was under the impression that in your case the elements have different types (I was assuming `p.Num` to be either an int or a float).

Comment: yes, that's right. but thank you for example and what if there list of structures ? if I got something like type x = {i:int s:string}

Answer (score 3):

To give you one more alternative solution, you can just create a filtered sequence containing values of the original type by writing `yield p`:

```
let x = [ for p in db.ParamsActXes do
            if p.NumGroupPar = grp then
              yield p ]
```

And then just access the property you need:

```
let str = "hello" + x.[1].Name
```

This is probably a good idea if you're returning only several properties of the `p` value. The only reason for yielding tuples would be to hide something from the rest of the code or to create sequence that matches some function you use later.

(Also, I would avoid indexing into lists using `x.[i]`, because this is inefficient - but maybe this is just for ilustration in the sample you posted. Use an array if you need index based access by wrapping sequence expression into `[| ... |]`)

Answer (score 2):

Just to throw one more possibility out there, if you are running the .NET 4.0 build of F# 2.0 you can perform a runtime cast from the F# tuple to the .NET 4.0 System.Tuple and then use the `ItemX` properties of the .NET 4.0 tuples to access the tuple element you need,

```
let x = (1, 1.2, "hello")
let y = ((box x) :?> System.Tuple<int, float, string>);;
y.Item3 //returns "hello"
```

However, I would never use that, instead opting for the pattern match extraction. (also, I've read places that the F# compiler may not always choose to represent its tuples as .NET 4.0 tuples, so there may be a possibility that the cast would fail).

Reading your comments in some of the other answers, I'm unsure why the pattern matching solution doesn't work for you. Perhaps you want to access the tuple item at a certain place within an expression?  If so, the previous would certainly work:

```
let str = "hello" + ((box x.[1]) :?> System.Tuple<int,string>).Item2 //though might as well use snd and fst for length 2 F# tuples
```

but you can achieve the same ends using the pattern matching extraction technique too (again, assuming this is even what you're after):

```
let str = "hello" + (let (_,name) = x.[1] in name)
```

Comment: +1 for the embedded let in the expression. It's easy to forget you can do that when used to statement-based languages.

Comment: @Joh - indeed! I believe that understanding F#'s non-light syntax really helps you gain a deeper feel for the language (possibly see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677169/functions-in-f-why-is-it-not-compiling/4682976#4682976). let bindings being a good example, where using the light syntax, it's easy to mistake them for imperative style assignment statements. And for a beginner, it can be confusing to reconcile assertions that in F# "everything is an expression". That being said, I am definitely a fan of the light syntax!

Answer (score 1):

you can access individual tuple from the list of tuple using List.nth.

```
let first, second = List.nth x 0
```

first and second represents the individual element of the tuple.