# F# member constraints on tuples

Tags: generics, f#, constraints

I commonly have a "oh yeah" moment writing F# when I realize I need an extra value somewhere.  This is generally easily done by adding another value to the tuple being passed around.  However, this means that various maps/sorts/collects/etc. need updating, and in particular the functions fst/snd only work on tuples of length 2.

It's not a huge issue, but it's annoying enough during exploratory development that I though I'd write a helper to alleviate the annoyance:

```
let inline get2 (t:^a) = (^a : (member get_Item2 : unit -> string) (t, ()))
let inline get2a (t:^a) = (^a : (member Item2 : string) t)
```

However, both versions do not work.  The first, `get2`, won't compile, with "Expected 1 expressions, got 2".   The second, `get2a`, will compile, but subsequently can't be used on tuples: "The type '(int * string)' does not support any operators named 'get_Item2'".

Is there any way of doing this that doesn't involve lots of overloads? <strike>with noisy `OverloadID` annotations</strike> *(annotations not required in F# 2.0)*

Comment: Aside - why is C++ still the only language with flexible, practical generics - the constraint would have been inferred, would work, and in any case would be unnecessary due to numeric template parameters...

Comment: The `OverloadID` attribute hasn't been required since F# 2.0

Comment: Hey that's nice to know!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason why `ItemX` static constraints on F# tuples do not work is because `System.Tuple<_,...,_>` is only the encoded form of tuples, and not the static representation used by the compiler. See [6.3.2 Tuple Expressions](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc270597440) in the specification.

However, with a little work, you can obtain the runtime encoding of a given tuple like so:

```
open System
//like get2a but generic return type
let inline get2b (t:^a) = (^a : (member Item2 : 'b) t)

let x = (1,2)
let y = (1,2,3)

get2b (box x :?> Tuple<int,int>)
get2b (box y :?> Tuple<int,int,int>)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using reflection:

```
let inline get (t:^a) = t.GetType().GetProperty("Item2").GetValue(t,null) :?> string
```

Also, I would suggest that tuples are not really a great data structure for passing data around, they may be useful inside a function for small operations, but in case there is a frequent change in the structure, tuple can be really painful to work with

Comment: I have tried doing what Eamon wants a while back, and if I remember right - your solution is the only.

Comment: The whole point is to do this during exploratory development; I don't have types defined yet because they're changing all the time.  So this kind of thing would be purely local but using explicit records is less ideal since that means changing their definition (and indeed needing to have a definition) which I'm likely to redo anyhow once the code starts shaping up.

Comment: Ok, then I think using reflection in case of exploratory dev wont be much of an issue with respect to performance

Comment: Using reflection to get the arbitrary nth element of a tuple: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252628/how-can-i-refer-to-a-specific-member-of-a-tuple-of-any-size-in-f/5255181#5255181

Comment: Performance is an issue - if it's not snappy, it's not useful as an exploratory tool.  I'd have to measure it to find out whether the slowdown is significant, however.

Comment: hmm, and it looks like reflection will break type-inference; I guess long lists of overloads it is.

Comment: @Eamon Nerbonne - unfortunately, overloads will break type-inference as well: http://fssnip.net/6V

Comment: So a general `fst` function is impossible in F#; I guess?

Comment: It is not just F# case, it will be same for any statically typed language

Comment: It's possible in C++ for example, and Haskell's type classes would make something similar possible too.  Even plain overloads *work*, and type inference is possible, just not performed.  Really, it's trivial to reason about statically, so I don't see what being a statically checked language has to do with it - it's just not implemented, apparently.