# Is it possible to create an extension method for an F# Tuple

Tags: generics, f#, extension-methods, tuples

I am trying to create a type augmentation method for an F# tuple. This code compiles just fine:

```
type System.Tuple<'a, 'b> with
    member this.ToParameter name =
        match this with
        | this -> sprintf "%s=%O,%O" name (this.Item1, this.Item2)
```

However, when I try to invoke this method:

```
printfn "%s" (("cat", 2).ToParameter("test"))
```

I get an error saying "This field, constructor or member 'ToParameter' is not defined." In the interpreter, the following expressions report their type as being some form of System.Tuple'2:

```
typedefof<'a * 'b>.FullName
(1, 2).GetType().FullName
```

In the Visual Studio, if I hover over the expression:

```
let a = 1, 2
```

It reports a type of int * int. When I try to augment this type, or it's generic equivalent, 'a * 'b, I get an error.

Is it possible to create a generic augmentation for the F# tuple?

Comment: Any particular reason for making this an extension method (as opposed to a function)?

Comment: I'd like to be able to call ToParameter on may types. I have the augmentation working for IEnumerable<'a>, string, and others. To create a single function that would handle all of these types, I would have to resort to boxing, and reflection. I could create a different method for each type, but this makes the API less readable.

Comment: Why not just create a type with overloaded methods - then you would just have `utils.ToParameter(t)` instead of `t.ToParameter()` which would seem ok

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your question will be pretty much the same as the answer I gave to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6859564/236255). That is, the reason why your type extension does not work is because "`System.Tuple<_,...,_>` is only the encoded form of tuples, and not the static representation used by the compiler. See [6.3.2 Tuple Expressions](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc270597440) in the specification."

To use your type extension, you'll have to first box and then cast your tuple value:

```
let tuple = box ("cat", 2) :?> System.Tuple<string,int>
printfn "%s" (tuple.ToParameter("test"))
```

Aside: also note that you had a slight syntax error in your type extension, it should be:

```
type System.Tuple<'a, 'b> with
    member this.ToParameter name =
        match this with
        | this -> sprintf "%s=%O,%O" name this.Item1 this.Item2 //removed parens around Item1 and Item2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use C# style extension methods, but notice you have an error in your definition of `ToParameter`, arguments should be curried:

```
open System.Runtime.CompilerServices

[<Extension>]
type TupleExtensions () = 
    [<Extension>] static member ToParameter((a, b), name) = sprintf "%s=%O,%O" name a b

printfn "%s" (("cat", 2).ToParameter("test"))
```

The reason why using `System.Tuple` doesn't work it's because at compile-time .NET tuples and F# syntactic tuples they are treated as different types. This might change in future versions of the compiler.